# Can same Android app with same application id can send crash reports into two different Firebase Console (Crashlytics)

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have 2 different Firebase accounts and created a project inside it with same package name(com.sonyliv). Now it runs f fine with my 1st Firebase account-(every crash reports are coming into this) but now while releasing in production ,we need to change the Firebase Account cause we got it from Client.

For this - all i am doing is changing the google-services.json file which is generated in 2nd Firebase Account of same app with same package name(com.sonyliv).

But by default - when app crashes - all crash reports is  going into 1st Firebase Account only.
Any idea .why ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your app is not linked to the second Firebase account. You may want to ask the client to add your app's package name to the second account, and then configure different credentials for debug and release environments using the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application).

Comment: They only created an app with same package name and given to us - if app not linked , google-services.json woudnt be generated

Answer (score 0):

- I assume two different accounts - Where apps are in two different Firebase projects, if that a case reach out to Firebase Support and ask them for transfer of ownership of the project/app in question. They will need Firebase project and package names.